# How to achieve the following in memoir class:

Tags: margins, memoir

Consider the example attached below, taken from the [memoir package documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf).

I would like to be able to replicate how the words "lines" and "nearest" appear in the margins. For example, say I am defining Coulomb's Law, I would like "Coulomb's Law" to appear in the margin in a similar fashion when I write about it in the main body text.

EDIT: I would like to achieve this without the use of a list environment, which for example @Vinccool96 has provided.

EDIT 2: I would like the command to apply to a specific word in a body of text, and produce result as shown in the screenshot, while also retaining the word in the body of text *without necessarily altering its in text appearance*, just adding the word again in the margin with the `\texttt{}` font.

[image: Example of what I would like to achieve]

Comment: You are not by chance just looking for `\marginpar`?

Comment: I don't believe so. I would like for example to do the following:  \command{word} and have the word appear both as in the screenshot provided in as well as in the body of text.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\mykeyword}[1]{\reversemarginpar\marginpar{\texttt{#1}}\texttt{#1}}
\begin{document}
bla bla \mykeyword{word} bla
\lipsum[1-7]

bla bla \mykeyword{another word} bla
\lipsum[8-12]

\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you simple want to write an important word into the margin of your document.

Please see the following MWE (important code marked with `<=====`)

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{blindtext} % <========================= to create dummy text
\usepackage{showframe} % <========= to visualize typing area and margins
\newcommand{\myimportant}[1]{%
  \marginpar{\texttt{#1}}#1% <========= text in margin same text in text
}


\begin{document} 
\blindtext
blafasel \myimportant{word} % <=========================================
blub \blindtext 

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: text in margin]

Be careful: too many `\myimportant` commands near to each other can result in ugly output ...

Comment: I suggested almost the same in [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482309/how-to-achieve-the-following-in-memoir-class#comment1219177_482309) but the OP seems not to like it.

Answer (score 0):

I uses the `itemize` environment with custom labels, the text is made with the `\texttt{}` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item[\texttt{lines}] This is similar to \texttt{classic}, but results in a 
        smaller final value.
        \item[\texttt{nearest}] The calculated value is the nearest to the given value
        while still maintaining the relationship
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would I do this without the itemize environment, say when I am in text?

Comment: You asked how the ``memoir`` package creators did it, no? I looked at the ``.tex`` file they used to produce their documentation and gave you their source code ([found here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/doc-src), it's the [``memman.tex`` file](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/doc-src/memman.tex))

Comment: Yes, I did ask how to replicate it, but mentioned that I would like to do this within the main body of text. I have added a clarification as my original question could be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

In `memoir` you can use the `\marginpar` macro; see chapter 12 in the documentation (`> texdoc memoir`). For example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newcommand*{\mymarginpar}[1]{\marginpar{#1}#1}
\begin{document}
This is similar to lines\marginpar{lines} but produces a smaller value.

The calculated value is \mymarginpar{nearest} to the given value while
still maintaining a relationship.
\end{document}
```

Depending on how you want everything to look you might want to add additional information (like fonts to use) in the `\marginpar` macro. read the manual for additional information.